# EmptyBorder around JCheckBox becomes visible when checkbox selected

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I've set an `EmptyBorder` around my `JCheckBox` (for the purpose of indenting it, but that doesn't really matter). When I select (or deselect) my `JCheckBox`, the border gets drawn around it as a dashed black line. I don't want to even see this border at all. How do I keep it invisible?

Here is my (simplified) code:

```
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
JCheckBox myCB = new JCheckBox("hello");
myPanel.add(myCB);
myCB.setBorder( new EmptyBorder( 2, 15, 2, 2 ) );
```

Comment: Maybe try not adding a border and instead use a proper positioning mechanism to indent the checkbox...?

Comment: Are you sure this is not just what it looks like when an item is focused on your OS/L&F? `EmptyBorder` shouldn't have a visual component.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It doesn't matter if that's what I'm using the border for. I could be using it for any reason, but I'd still want it not to appear.

Comment: @Radiodef It's probably what you're suggesting, because I wouldn't think it should do that either. I'm using Windows XP, FWIW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the border gets drawn around it as a dashed black line. I don't want to even see this border at all.

That is not a Border. That sounds like the focus indicator which indicates the component has focus. All components have some kind of focus indicator to give feedback to the user.

Companies spend millions of dollars to have a consistent LAF, but if you really think your LAF is better then you can use:

```
checkbox.setFocusPainted( false );
```

Comment: Perfect. Explains what is happening, gives me a solution, and warns me of the implications.