# Visually indicate focus of a focusable JLabel on different LAFs

Tags: java, swing, focus, jlabel

I have created some focusable `JLabels` and would like to visually indicate when one of them has focus keeping it consistent with current look and feel.

The closest thing to this that come to mind are `JCheckBox` and `JButton` focus indicators, but I cannot find where those are defined. I would have expected them to be borders accessible through LAF defaults, but this doesn't seem to be the case. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22970916/878469) by camickr mentions that those are not even borders. So what are they? Are they painted in a completely implementation dependent way?

How can I mimic the focus indicator of a `JCheckBox` or a `JButton` for a `JLabel` on different platforms? I'm currently using `label.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("List.focusCellHighlightBorder"))` but that only looks okay on some LAFs.

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JButtonFocusBorder extends JFrame {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JTextField textfield1;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JTextField textfield2;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JCheckBox checkbox1;
    private JButton button;

    public JButtonFocusBorder() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        initComponents();

        label1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
        label2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));

        label1.setFocusable(true);
        label2.setFocusable(true);

        FocusListener focusListener = new FocusAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
                // looking for a replacement of this
                label.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("List.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
                label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
            }
        };
        label1.addFocusListener(focusListener);
        label2.addFocusListener(focusListener);

        MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
                label.requestFocusInWindow();
            }

        };
        label1.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        label2.addMouseListener(mouseListener);

        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        add(panel);

        GridBagConstraints gbc;

        label1 = new JLabel("Field1:");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(label1, gbc);        

        textfield1 = new JTextField(20);
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(textfield1, gbc);

        label2 = new JLabel("Field2:");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(label2, gbc);        

        textfield2 = new JTextField(20);
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(textfield2, gbc);

        checkbox1 = new JCheckBox("CheckBox1");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(checkbox1, gbc);

        button = new JButton("Apply");
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(button, gbc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws 
            ClassNotFoundException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException, 
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());


        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JButtonFocusBorder().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

P.S.: This question is related to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33017754/878469) of one of my existing questions and explains why I'd want focusable labels.

Comment: and by using Nimbus L&F content jumping on the screen (focus enlarge the JLables bound, that unforntatelly are accepted, repainted by LayoutManager), you have to use EmptyBorders to avoids of those funny repainting artefacts

Comment: @mKorbel, that's because on Nimbus `List.focusCellHighlightBorder` border probably isn't the same size as the `EmptyBorders` I'm (already) creating in the example. Like I said, only works on some LAFs.

Comment: 1. border probably isn't the same size as the EmptyBorders ?= Insets, 2. label, description for JCheckBox hasn't any border, 3. for JButtonComponents to use events from ButtonModel (or the same events are implemented in JButtons/AbstractButton APIs and correctly)

Comment: It might be easier to use a JButton